# iOS : display svg from JSON

Tags: ios, json, rest, svg, svgkit

I'm trying to display a svg file in my iOS application.

The svg file is given to me by a REST API. So I end up with an answer like this from the API :

```
{
   "response": {
      "data": {
         “var2”: “svgCodeXML”
      }, "status": "ok"
   } 
}
```

Currently I'm displaying it in a web view and it's displaying.

I'd like to display the svg directly in my iOS app, without a web view.

I've been looking at the SVGKit library but I haven't found a way to do it.

Do anybody know how to achieve this purpose?

Thank you very much.

Comment: `SVGKit` does not support loading images from a string, so you will have to save the SVG XML to a file and load it from there with `SVGKit`.

Comment: I think they currently do support loading from a string by using `SVGKParser`?

Comment: SVGKit has supported loading from string for a couple of years now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using SVG kit. You can find the code and examples here: https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit

Answer (score 0):

Starting Xcode 12

> **Asset Catalogs**
>
> **New Features**
>
> Added support for Scalable Vector Graphic (SVG) image assets. These preserve their vector representation with deployment targets of macOS 10.15 or later, iOS 13 or later, and iPadOS 13 or later. (18389814)

source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-12-beta-release-notes

Comment: but this is **Asset Catalogs**... How that works if you get the svg image from REST API and try to display it in UIImageView?